# can any one tell me how can i remove preflight request from this $http header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    //individual logins
    $rootScope.setting.instances.forEach(function(ins) {

        var header = { 
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa( ins.uname + ':' + ins.pword ),
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, JSONP"

                };      

         $http({ method : 'post', url : ins.url, headers: header })
         .success( function( data )
         {
            console.log( ins.name +" login success" );
            $("#fail" + ins.id ).hide();
            $("#succ" + ins.id ).show();
            //logins : a global variable declared in app.js
            logins.push('{"ins" : '+ ins.id + ',"isAvailable" : "true"}');
            checkFinished();
         })
         .error( function( data)
         {
            console.log( ins.name +" login failed" );
            $("#fail" + ins.id ).show();
            $("#succ" + ins.id ).hide();
            //logins : a global variable declared in app.js
            logins.push('{"ins" : '+ ins.id + ',"isAvailable" : "false"}');
            checkFinished();
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure, remove the authorization header. Also, the access control headers don't belong on the client side.

Comment: Yep.I got it.but the thing is this is  a angularjs  app build to push data into   other machines.{instances}.every time  to acess to those machines it need to send ins.name and  ins.url.that is must.in order  to  push data.so  authorisation  is required.having  those  parts  can  i  still  override the  preflight security  feature?

Answer (score 0):

The CORS specification requires a browser to preflight the request with the OPTIONS request if any custom headers are specified on the cross origin request. And, when it does the OPTIONS preflight, it does not include your custom headers because part of what the OPTIONS request is for is to find out what custom headers are allowed to be sent on the request. So, a server is not supposed to require custom headers on the OPTIONS request if it wants this to work from a browser.

So, if you don't want it to preflight with the OPTIONS request, then you have to not use custom headers on the request.